# Getopt not included? implicit declaration of function ‘getopt’

Tags: c, linux, getopt

I wanted to use getopt, but it just won't work.

It's giving me

```
gcc -g -Wall -std=c99 -ftrapv -O2 -Werror -Wshadow -Wundef -save-temps -Werror-implicit-function-declaration   -c -o src/main.o src/main.c
src/main.c: In function ‘main’:
src/main.c:13:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘getopt’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
src/main.c:23:14: error: ‘optarg’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/main.c:23:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
src/main.c:26:9: error: ‘optopt’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/main.c:28:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘isprint’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
src/main.c:36:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘abort’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
src/main.c:36:5: error: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’ [-Werror]
src/main.c:43:15: error: ‘optind’ undeclared (first use in this function)
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [src/main.o] Error 1
```

Here's the source if you wanna see it
(almost exact copypasta from getopt manpage)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> // getopt
#include "myfn.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int aflag = 0;
    int bflag = 0;
    char *cvalue = NULL;
    int c;

    while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "abc:")) != -1) {

        switch(c) {
            case 'a':
                aflag = 1;
                break;
            case 'b':
                bflag = 1;
                break;
            case 'c':
                cvalue = optarg;
                break;
            case '?':
                if (optopt == 'c')
                    fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
                else if (isprint(optopt))
                    fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
                else
                    fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n", optopt);

                return 1;

            default:
                abort ();
        }

    }

    printf ("aflag = %d, bflag = %d, cvalue = %s\n", aflag, bflag, cvalue);

    for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++) {
        printf ("Non-option argument %s\n", argv[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I'm on Linux, so I assumed it should work like this.

Comment: just something I used to debug makefile, it's of no importance.

Comment: Why you want to use the flag -implicit-function-declaration in this case.

Comment: @tmp it gives exact same error even with just `-g -Wall -std=c99`

Comment: on what kind of system you are working? did you had a look at unistd.h ? does it contain getopt?

Comment: Xubuntu 12.04. Of course it can be some packages missing, but I can'tn figure out where getopt should be.

Comment: Well I think(gcc -std=c99 main.c -o main) should work fine and it seems to be working fine. which version of gcc is running on your machine?

Comment: @MightyPork It's working for me. which linux distro you use also try first simple like `gcc prog.c -o prog` then makefile

Comment: It's GCC 4.6.3. I tried `gcc main.c -o main -std=c99` but it gives the same error as before.

Comment: @MightyPork have tried with flag `-std=gnu99`?

Comment: i did, it wouldn't work as well. It's solved now thanks to @Guntram Blohm, thanks guys for suggestions!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try removing the `-std=c99`. This disables the GNU extensions and thus prevents the POSIX macros from being defined in `<features.h>`, which prevents `<unistd.h>` from including `<getopt.h>`.
Or replace the flag by `-std=gnu99`.
Or include `getopt.h` yourself.

It is a GNU extension that `getopt()` is part of `unistd.h`. By setting `-std=c99` no GNU extensions are used, the function is no longer declared and you need to explicitly include `getopt.h`.

Comment: I'll try this. But I want to declare for loop variables inside the loop, that's why I have c99.

Comment: No problem. Just add another `#include <getopt.h>` to your source.

Comment: @MightyPork you can try with `-std=gnu99`  instead `-std=c99.`

Comment: Got it working, the std flag was indeed the problem. Now happily compiling with `-std=c99` and `#include <getopt.h>`. But do I still need `unistd.h` now? (btw what's the difference b/w c99 and gnu99?)

Comment: @GuntramBlohm: nice catch +1. Btw i just wanted to know whether you checked the unistd.h file and see how getopt.h is included or you was aware about this.

Comment: @tmp: I'm used to including `getopt.h` when i use `getopt` (because when i use `getopt`, i use the gnu versions anyway), and i wasn't sure if `unistd.h` included `getopt.h` at all.  So i grepped for `getopt` in `unistd.h`, checked the context, checked the context of `__USE_POSIX2` in `features.h`, then it became clear what was happening.

Comment: `getopt` is a GNU extension to C. If you restrict yourself to ISO C (`-std=c99`) it will not be available. Use `-std=gnu99` if you can, or include `getopt.h` manually (be aware of portability issues, as not all platforms provide `getopt.h`)

Comment: `getopt` is *not* a GNU extension but standardized in POSIX.

Answer (score 3):

You cloud not remove `-std=c99`.
Instead, add `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 2` at beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Add `#include <getopt.h>` among the includes.

Comment: This suggestion is already part of the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

There is absolute no need to change the `-std` or to include `getopt.h` directly.

The right thing to do if you want to use the C99 (or any other standardized) language features together with POSIX functions (like `getopt`) is to define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to the right version (e.g., `200809L`) before including the respective headers. For more details see feature_test_macros(7).

Answer (score -4):

I had the same issue, the way to fix it is you're most likely compiling with `-std=c99`, but instead try `-std=gnu99` and it should work.

Comment: This is already explained in the accepted answer.